# Are the columns used in the order / group by clause(s) mandatory in the select clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Oracle database allows the following queries:

```
select col1 from table order by col2;

select count(col1) from table group by col2;
```

It appears that the columns in the order / group by clause don't need to be in the select clause. However, [tutorialspoint: SQL - ORDER BY Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-order-by.htm) tells me otherwise. Is the above only Oracle specific then?

Comment: This is one of the areas where the syntax/behaviour is somewhat specific to each RDBMS. If my memory serves me correctly, early SQL implementations required all columns in the `SELECT` clause to be either in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregated columns like `COUNT(*)` or `MAX(amt)`. Later implementations have relaxed this and improved flexibility/functionality but with some divergence between the different implementations. Best to check the manuals for your specific version of your RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is just plain wrong.

An `order by` can include any columns in the queried objects whether they are in the select list or not.

A `group by` goes the other way. Any non-aggregated columns in the select list must be included in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the case that columns mentioned in the `GROUP BY` must be in the `SELECT`. However, if there is a `GROUP BY` then columns in the `SELECT`, that aren't aggregated, must be in the `GROUP BY`! Anyway, please see [SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2469f6/1) for MySQL. So you can see that it is not Oracle-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the order in which the results are produced, it becomes clear that you need not select the same column from the result returned by the query conditions.

As far as the order is concerned,first the records are selected from the table, then they are ordered by the column you specified in the query and then you can select the column or attributes you wish to see in the result or output.

Hope it helps!